# Auto Log on enter to every method in c# project

Tags: c#, logging

Is there a possibility to log every call of methods (stack trace etc.) without adding code to this method. What I want is to check on which method application stuck, but I do not want to add log code to every method.

It stuck but doesn't throw an error, so try catch with stack trace wouldn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's worth trying an [AOP-based approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), such as [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp). You can use attributes on either classes or individual methods to control the logging.

For example, there's a [PostSharp plugin to integrate with log4net](http://code.google.com/p/postsharp-user-plugins/wiki/Log4PostSharp).

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely can't touch the code at all then running the code in a profiler should help identify which method is getting stuck, at least you'll see it as a long running method provided it isn't throwing an exception and just exiting.

For example, Red Gate's Ants Performance Profiler is one such tool:

> [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to Jon's answer I've been looking at [AspectDNG](http://aspectdng.tigris.org/nonav/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try "Process Explorer" to identify stucked call. You can find it at
: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Answer (score 0):

Use a debugger to attach to the process that's stuck?